# Is supermesh the right way to go?

Tags: circuit-analysis, mesh-analysis

I have this problem and I'm wondering if using the Supermesh method is the right way to go?
When assigning how the currents are flowing they should be clockwise, but how should I think when the current is flowing the other way?

[image]

Could someone lead me into the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the superposition theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been here long enough, I think, to be aware of the schematic editor. It's helpful (saves me time, anyway) if you bother, because the parts get labeled and it's easier to ask you clarifying questions. (But if all you have is a cell phone, it may be the case that you can only add pictures.) That said, here's the schematic I wish you'd drawn:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6XQWc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've kept the general format you provided, but as you can see parts are labeled and so are a few nodes. You may notice that I've selected one of the nodes as "ground." You get to do this for exactly one node of your choice. I picked that one, but you could choose a different one if you want. It won't change the answers to the questions. Still, I like my choice better than others. So that's my call.

One thing you should remember is that the impedance of a current source is infinite. So \$I_1\$ in series with \$R_2\$ as shown above means that you can just short out \$R_2\$ (remove it, replacing it with a wire.) That's because \$R_2\$'s value is vanishingly small compared to the theoretical impedance of \$I_1\$. So it contributes nothing to the analysis.

Another way to see this is that although \$I_1\$ causes a \$5\:\text{V}\$ drop across \$R_2\$, you don't know the voltage across \$I_1\$ which can be anything. So the voltage across \$I_1\$ just "adapts." Inserting a resistor just means it adapts to a different voltage value. But the summed voltage drop across the series pair, \$I_1\$ and \$R_2\$, will be the same no matter what the value of \$R_2\$ is.

We can rewrite the above schematic, now, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftQ9LV.png)</sup>

Now, this isn't all you can simplify. \$I_1\$, no matter its value, has zero impact on the node marked as \$+4\:\text{V}\$. There is a voltage source that is holding that node's value. So we can re-write the schematic as follows, without impacting any of the analysis you require:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq66yX.png)</sup>

By now, if not before, I think you can see that the two current sources connected to node **A** result in a net current that must flow through \$R_3\$ (due to KCL.) So you should have a very firm grip on the value of \$I_3\$ at this point. It just "falls out," if it hadn't beforehand.

You can how replace \$R_3\$ with that value of current (which I'm sure you can easily find.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd9JOM.png)</sup>

At this point, all you need to do is work out the voltage value of node **B** and you will be able to work out the other two currents.

This is a very simple equation using KCL:

$$\frac{V_\text{B}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{B}}{R_4}=I_3+\frac{V_1=+4\:\text{V}}{R_1}$$

I think this should allow you to completely resolve the circuit without any worries over simultaneous equations. Nothing more than a bit of simple algebraic manipulation of a single equation and you'll have all you need to solve for the remaining two currents.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the well explained solution. I have calculated I3 = 2mA and I understand the left part of the KCL equation, however I have a hard time understanding the right part of it. I get the right part to 0.004, however I don't understand how I can work it out from there.

Comment: @Vetenskap Just to explain how I set up the equation, I've placed the outgoing-currents on the left side of the equation and the incoming-currents on the right side. These must, by KCL, balance. (Be equal.) Solving this equation, algebraically, should be an easy stint for you. Extract the common factor, \$V_\text{B}\$, on the left side and then simply divide both sides by what's needed so that only \$V_\text{B}\$ remains on the left side.

Comment: Just so I'm on the right path. I calculated Vb = 5.33 V. Now the only thing that I need to do is to just calculate the currents Vb/R1 and Vb/R4, is that correct?

Comment: @Vetenskap Yes. I think you have it!

Comment: Thank you good sir! I got it at the end! :)

Answer (score 0):

> When assigning how the currents are flowing they should be clockwise, but how should I think when the current is flowing the other way?

If you define that the positive current / the mesh current flows clockwise and the arrow of the current source points in the opposite direction, that current will be negative.

Answer (score 0):

The current source is good in that if you pick your loops correctly, it instantly solves the current for one loop. But if the current source is sitting on the boundary of between more than one loop then it becomes an annoyance if the current source is sitting in the path of a KVL loop where the current source is not solely responsible for the loop current because to solve the KVL you need to calculate the unknown voltage drop of the current source.

So one thing you can do is to pick a such that the the current's value immediately solves the loop current for that loop so you do not need to KVL, and then use a supermesh that encompasses, but does not run through the current source for components that you do need to KVL so you do not need to account for the voltage drop across the current source.

---

You can assign unknown current directions in a loop however you want as long as you are also consistent in the way you assume unknown voltage drops caused by that current. I tend to make all currents go go counter-clockwise and assume that all my unknown voltage drops are a load. That is, I assume if my assumed current direction flows causes an unknown voltage drop, it produces a voltage drop with the polarity consistent with a load (not a source). If your assumption is right, you will end up with positive current. If its wrong you will end up with negative current.